# Не заносятся данные таблицу MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Весь код ниже работает кроме последней строки. Все переменные выводятся правильно, но не заносятся в БД.
Типы переменных в БД:

**ID_Order** - *int(11)*, он автоинкремент, поэтому не заполняю.
**Date_Order** - *datetime*.
**Price_order** - *int(11)*.
**ID_Patient** - *int(11)*.

```
 $price = $_POST['price'];
 print_r($price);
 $analysis = array();
 $analysis[] = $_POST['analysis'];
 print_r($analysis);
 $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
 print_r($date);
 $id_patient = $_POST['patient'];
 print_r($id_patient);
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO Orders SET Date_order ='".$date."', Price_order = 
 $price, ID_Patiet = '".$id_patient."' ");
```

Comment: вроде логично отсюда сделать вывод, что что-то не так с сами запросом? Например, почитать про синтаксис инструкции `insert` для начала, а потом еще вспомнить что расширение `mysql_*` устарело и вовсе отсутствует в современных версиях пхп. И еще чего нить про подстановку параметров в запросы бы не мешало узнать. А чтобы таких вопросов не возникало, достаточно проверять результат выполнения `mysql_query` и смотреть на сообщения об ошибках

Comment: 1. после выполнения запроса проверяйте на ошибки БД и если они есть выводите их. 2. не используйте устаревшее расширение mysql. Используйте PDO или в крайнем случае mysqli и при этом используйте подготавливаемые выражения и привязку переменных

Comment: Согласен с Mike в предыдущем комментарии. mysqli_query используйте, а также возможно у вас ошибка в названии колонки таблицы https://prnt.sc/jfia6x . Плюс рекомендую запрос сначала полностью прописать в переменную, его распечатать, и далее используя Phpmyadmin (например) попробовать этот запрос - вам выведется ошибка. Это актуально если нет под рукой рабочей среды полноценной.

Comment: Пожалуйста! Добавьте ошибку в свой вопрос, чтобы можно было дать на него ответ.